# Opening https with phantomjs on OpenShift

Tags: phantomjs, openshift

I am using OpenShift, and using following code to open http url with phantomjs (in order to take screenshot), http works fine but HTTPS fails with status code null. I know this is very specific question and problem for openshift but looks like openshift want users to ask all questions on SO now.

```
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you saying if you try to load a https address using phantomjs on openshift it fails?  I'm currently writing an app using phantomjs. Everything (https) works fine locally. I have not pushed to openshift yet.

Comment: That's correct, http works great but https doesn't. Let me know if worked for you.

Comment: Any luck so far?  I have not forgotten about you. I have been side tracked this week. Hopefully I should be able to test on openshift next week and will post back.

Comment: I was able to push my app to Openshift today. All of my Phantomjs Https stuff worked fine.

Comment: Hey, what type of gear are you using to run phantomjs on openshift? Although my primary skills are java but I was trying phantomjs with PHP to take screenshots. Although it should not make any difference, because the script I pasted above was pure js, which version of phantomjs are you on?

Comment: I running phantomjs and casperjs under the python 3.3 cartridge on OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on making this work on openshift and eventually I just moved to heroku and the same code on heroku worked like charm.